# Calling anonymous function within anonymous function (Inception)

Tags: php, anonymous-function

Simple question, but tough answer? I have the following anonymous function inside a class method:

```
$unnest_array = function($nested, $key) {
    $unnested = array();

    foreach ($nested as $value) {
        $unnested[] = (object) $value[$key];
    }

    return $unnested;
};
```

In the same class method I have this array, where I save anonymous functions. I.e. I create a new anonymous function using the inline `create_function()` and I would want to use the already defined anonymous function `$unnest_array()`. Is it possible?

```
$this->_funcs = array(
    'directors' => array(
        'func'  => create_function('$directors', 'return $unnest_array($directors, "director");'),
        'args'  => array('directors')
    )
);
```

At the moment I am getting "Undefined variable: unnest_array". Help?

Comment: You might want to refer to that as closures... and delete everything.

Comment: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) calls them anonymous functions as well as closures. Why delete everything?

Comment: plus 1 even just for the inception part :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `create_function` in the first place? Closures replace `create_function` entirely, leaving it essentially obsolete in all versions of PHP after 5.3. It seems like you're trying to [partially apply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) `$unnest_array` by fixing the second argument as `"director"`.

Unless I've misunderstood you, you should be able to achieve the same result by using a closure/anonymous function (untested):

```
$this->_funcs = array(
    'directors' => array(
        'func'  => function($directors) use ($unnest_array)
            {
                return $unnest_array($directors, "director");
            },
        'args'  => array('directors')
    )
);
```

The `use ($unnest_array)` clause is necessary to access local variables in the parent scope of the closure.

Comment: Little correction: `use ($unnest_array)` instead of `using $unnest_array`.

Comment: @hakra: Thanks, my bad. It's been a while since I used PHP!

Comment: You read me perfectly, thank you! I wasn't aware of the `use` keyword.